# MySQL fulltext search with different permutations

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, mysql-error-1064

I am creating a mysql fulltext search engine for my website, and I have an advanced search page that allows the user to limit which columns they would like to search under. However, whenever I make a fulltext search index, all the columns used in that index must be used or else I get an error message. Is there any way to make a mysql index for fulltext where I can use just some of the columns?

For example I have 5 columns in my index, made by this statement:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD FULLTEXT fulltext_index(subject, course, prof, semester, 
year);
```

If I wanted to search under only subject and course, I would get the error:

```
#1191 - Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create more indexes for each possible combination you want to search:

alter table table1 add fulltext fulltext_index2(subject,course);

alter table table1 add fulltext fulltext_index3(course,semester,year);

Etc...see if that solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

No, a fulltext index requires you to use all of the columns. If you want to use only some of them, you'll need a separate fulltext index for every permutation. I haven't tested it, but you MAY get around it by using only columns in the order specified. e.g. an index on columns (a,b,c) might allow you to search only (a,b) because they're listed first, but not (a,c) or (b,c).